# open() "/root/project/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, permissions, django-staticfiles

I have gotta my project setup with `uwsgi, django, nginx`  Everything seems to be working fine but somehow I keep on getting the error on getting `static files` I have been reading through online and tried all the possible ways but I keep on getting this `permission denied` error on my static folder.

Can someone please let me know what I have done wrong with the permission and how I should change it?

this is my `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

`open() "/root/project/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 2xx.xx.xx.xxx, server: _, request: "GET /static/*.css HTTP/1.1", host: "1xx.xx.xx.xxx"`

This is my `nginx site-available config`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    #location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    #location /media  {
    #       root /root/project/mediafiles;
    #}


        location ^~ /static/ {
        allow all;  # this is from one of the posts but no luck
        auth_basic off;  # this is from one of the posts but no luck
            root /root/project;
        }


        location / {
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/uwsgi/project.sock;
        }

}
```

as my folder permission

for project folder it's `drwxr-xr-x 23 www-data www-data`

for static folder it's `drwxr-x---  8 www-data www-data 4096 May 23 14:40 static`

I never made the permission to static `755`  too but no luck.
Anyways, this is using root as user instead of having an extra user and root is also in group of `www-data`

Thanks in advance for all the help.

EDIT:

As suggested this is the output of `ps aux | grep nginx`

```
root       810  0.0  0.0 124972  1440 ?        Ss   02:18   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   811  0.0  0.0 125688  4840 ?        S    02:18   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   812  0.0  0.0 125348  3196 ?        S    02:18   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      1159  0.0  0.0  14224  1004 pts/0    S+   04:25   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Comment: Which user is nginx running as? Do a `ps aux | grep nginx` and share pls

Comment: @rtindru added your suggestion

Comment: Responded; please lmk if this works

Comment: keeping static contents in `/var/www/` location solves the problem. Because once you set `DEBUG=False`, django stops serving the static files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem I am guessing is the fact that your project `root` directory is at `/root`. The default permissions for `/root` are:

`drwx------  14 root root       4096 May  8 12:47 root`

As you can see, other users, such as `www-data` don't even have read access to the `/root` directory. In Linux FS, if you need to read something at a path`/a/b/c`, you need to have read access to each of the folders in that path.

The Nginx worker process runs as user `www-data` which is trying to open a file that is rooted at `/root` where this user does not have read permissions, and therefore raising a `Permission denied (13)`.

See this demo for more detail:

```
$ cat /root/test2/text.txt     
cat: /root/test2/text.txt: Permission denied
$ sudo cat /root/test2/test.txt  
A
$ sudo ls -la /root/ | grep test2
drwxrwxrwx   2 root     root       4096 May 24 02:04 test2
```

Hope this makes sense. The solution would be on of the following:

- Run nginx workers as root (not recommended)
- Move your project directory to a location that is designed to be accessed by multiple users such as `/usr/local/share` or `/var/www/` (recommended)

Comment: Your answer solved a problem that I had been having for a long time. Thank you

Comment: such as /usr/local/share or /var/www/ (recommended) - this saved my day! @rtindru thanks a lot! hope whoever facing this issue will get right solution from this answer in upcoming years too

Comment: Thank you so much, Moving my project to /usr/local/share or /var/www/ save my day.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My nginx server on Centos 7.6 can't access to static folder in path `/home/user/app/mysyte/static/`. In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` same error `open() "/home/user/app/mysyte/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied)`

For solving this problem look at this [page](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/) issue 2

Answer (score 1):

i was running into the same problem and i found this answer useful!

> Nginx connet to .sock failed (13:Permission denied) - 502 bad gateway

**What I simply did was changing the name of the user on the first line in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.**

In my case the default user was www-data and I changed it to my root machine username.

Comment: this might not be the best way to do it but buddy you saved my life. I was on it for 6 days. Thanks a tonn!!!

Answer (score 0):

As @rtindru said the solution to the problem is to move your project directory to a location that is designed to be accessed by multiple users such as /usr/local/share or /var/www/.
Here is a resource on how to do that
[the source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-nginx-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I had a similar issue of loading my static files and here are the commands i used to change.

```
sudo rsync -av /home/ubuntu/MyBlog/firstproject/static /var/www/
```

Where MyBlog/firstproject is the directory to my project. Remember to only change the static directory.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject
```

myproject is the directory created for ngnix.
add the following lines

```
server {

        root /var/www/static;
   
        . . .
}
```

And now restart the ngnix as suggested from source. Hope this works.