# How to exclude Nginx adding /index.html after my URL?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an alias for `ads.txt`, but when I access `/ads.txt` and I look in `error.log` this error occurs:

```
[error] 20051#20051: *457 "/root/public/front/public/ads.txt/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 172.70.55.104, server: server.com, request: "GET /ads.txt/ HTTP/2.0", host: "server.com"
```

(I've changed the URL to `server.com` for this question.)

That's my code for alias:

```
location /ads.txt {
   alias /root/public/front/public/ads.txt;
}
```

I've tried to change permissions because I'm having a problem with that before that error and this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
location /ads.txt {
   root /root/public/front/public/;
}
```

Comment: Don't work :(. That's the error that appears: 
`20513#20513: *295 directory index of "/root/public/front/public/" is forbidden, client: 172.70.54.56, server: server.com, request: "GET /ads.txt/ HTTP/2.0", host: "server.com"`
obs: note that nginx are adding / after ads.txt

Comment: Nginx does not have permission to open that file. Could you put the `public` dir in a place that nginx has access to?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I have front and back in different dir and if I made it probably will create more problems. How can I add perms to nginx acces the folder?

Comment: I changed the alias to root. Would you please try again and let me know the response?

Comment: `[error] 20946#20946: *600 "/root/public/front/public/ads.txt/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 172.70.82.91, server:server.com, request: "GET /ads.txt/ HTTP/2.0", host: "server.com"`

Comment: This answer addresses your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50497101/10059628. 
I got 200 with `root` to something like `/var/www/`. https://gitlab.com/monegim/test-ci/-/jobs/3998840113

Comment: Now if i put something before .txt (or withour it) my server responds with "Internal server error" and not redirect for my 404 page like before, but it's working lol